# Getting store item description

Tags: c#, ebay-api

I am currently using ebay api to retrieve data about store inventory listings:

[http://svcs.ebay.com/services/search/FindingService/v1?OPERATION-NAME=findItemsByCategory
&SERVICE-VERSION=1.11.0
&SECURITY-APPNAME=ENTER-APP-ID-HERE
&RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT=XML
&categoryId=307
&paginationInput.entriesPerPage=100
&paginationInput.pageNumber=1
&outputSelector=CategoryHistogram&sortOrder=EndTime&itemFilter%280%29.name=MinPrice&itemFilter%280%29.value=0.01&itemFilter%281%29.name=MaxPrice&itemFilter%281%29.value=10000
&itemFilter%282%29.name=ListingType&itemFilter%282%29.value=StoreInventory&itemFilter%283%29.name=LocatedIn&itemFilter%283%29.value=US
&itemFilter%284%29.name=EndTimeFrom&itemFilter%284%29.value=2011-08-06T07:52:48.000Z
&itemFilter%285%29.name=EndTimeTo&itemFilter%285%29.value=2011-08-30T07:52:48.000Z](http://svcs.ebay.com/services/search/FindingService/v1?OPERATION-NAME=findItemsByCategory%20&SERVICE-VERSION=1.11.0%20&SECURITY-APPNAME=ENTER-APP-ID-HERE%20&RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT=XML%20&categoryId=307%20&paginationInput.entriesPerPage=100%20&paginationInput.pageNumber=1%20&outputSelector=CategoryHistogram&sortOrder=EndTime&itemFilter%280%29.name=MinPrice&itemFilter%280%29.value=0.01&itemFilter%281%29.name=MaxPrice&itemFilter%281%29.value=10000%20&itemFilter%282%29.name=ListingType&itemFilter%282%29.value=StoreInventory&itemFilter%283%29.name=LocatedIn&itemFilter%283%29.value=US%20&itemFilter%284%29.name=EndTimeFrom&itemFilter%284%29.value=2011-08-06T07:52:48.000Z%20&itemFilter%285%29.name=EndTimeTo&itemFilter%285%29.value=2011-08-30T07:52:48.000Z)

I would like to know if there is a way to return the item description as well because right now it gives me only price, shipping price, and title, and some other small info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you include:

```
&IncludeSelector=Details,Description,TextDescription
```

in the call

eg.

http://open.api.ebay.com/shopping?callname=GetSingleItem&IncludeSelector=Details,Description,TextDescription&appid=YourAppId&version=515&ItemID=1111111111

Answer (score 2):

You need to call: [GetItem from the Trading API](http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/xml/docs/Reference/ebay/GetItem.html)

Answer (score 2):

If you are searching item in your store then you may use the trading API as answered by zang but if you want search in other stores

Use Ebay Finding API to get the item ID and then use shopping API and get both text and html description.

Answer (score 1):

The [`findItemsByCategory` response documentation](http://developer.ebay.com/devzone/finding/callref/findItemsByCategory.html#Response) doesn't include the store's freetext/HTML description of the store item. The closest nodes are `title` and `subtitle`, which obviously aren't what you're after.

It appears that the item description field won't be returned to you in this API call.